# What are the actual request headers sent in the Intellij HTTP client?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has an HTTP client. When composing a file that is interpreted by the HTTP client, you can specify headers that go out to the server with the request, like so:

```
###
GET https://{{hostname}}/{{path}}
Content-Type: application/json
X-Auth-Token: {{x-token}}
```

I want to find the actual value of the token that was used to replace the variable name, seen above as `{{x-token}}`, but I don't see any way to obtain the **request** headers. The **response** headers are obviously available, but not the request headers. See the image below for the test results that are shown after running the HTTP client inside Intellij:

[image]

Is there a way to display the REQUEST headers?

[Link to IntelliJ Documentation - HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) -- the documentation seems to never mention the **actual** request headers that are sent over the wire, but they do discuss how to define request headers in composing the `.http` file type.

Comment: These are values you define yourself, for the environment and then use them, see the [environment variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#environment-variables) section in the documentation.

Comment: You are correct; the request headers *are defined by me*. But, as you can see, I defined one to be a variable, which is replaced by *something to have a value that is only known at runtime or by the environment*, and I want to inspect this value on the client side. I do not want to have to open my server application to inspect the request headers.

Comment: Have you checked the Tools | HTTP Client | Show HHTP Requests History? Does it contain the information you need?

Comment: @Andrey that's exactly what I was looking for! It's so nice that the logs show this and allow you to resend the request. That's a perfect solution IntelliJ has implemented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Tools | HTTP Client | 'Show HHTP Requests History' action.